# Accessing a particular inputted Mysql user to php

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

**I want an inputted name of user and password(optional) of mysql user to be the one used as user instead of the default root. How do I improve this code where it can notify me that I have successfully used the user and warned me if the user is non existent.**

```
<form class="box login" method="post">
<fieldset class="boxBody">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username" required name="username">
  <label><label class="rLink" tabindex="5">Optional</label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" name="password" >
</fieldset>
<footer>

  <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Login" tabindex="4" name="submit">
</footer>
```

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$servername = "localhost";
$user = $username;
$pass = $password;

 if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
            echo  "Username can't be empty!"; }
    else {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass);
            if (!$conn) {
                 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
                    echo "Connected successfully"; }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're question is about how to improve functioning code it would be more appropriate at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if this isn't working for you please make the question more clear

Comment: this code is not functioning as I want it to be, like I stated I want it to notify me if it has successfully or failed to connect to the mysql user  that was inputted

Comment: So what does happen when you run this, and what would you prefer to see happen?